# Axios GET route 404-ing, Node.js/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I have the following simple GET inside a function.

```
axios
     .get(`/api/search/q=${this.value}`)
     .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
        });
```

The GET 404's if I enter a query (the letter 'a' in this case):

```
GET http://localhost:7777/api/search/q=a 404 (Not Found)
```

so, of course I get an Uncaught promise error from the .then:

```
 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
```

I figured that it must be a simple routing problem, but my express route is:

```
router.get('/api/search', someController.someFunction)
```

The function in the controller works (ie responds with the data) as I have used it elsewhere in the app, so I feel that I have narrowed it down to the axios GET not finding the api. But I can't figure out why, as the path looks OK to me.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `/api/search?q=a` instead?

Comment: If you are meaning to pass a query string then url should be `api/search?q=value`, if it is a URL param, then `api/search/:q`

Answer (score 0):

You were 404 getting because node is expecting only **/api/search** but your trying **/api/search/:q** which is different altogether, try

```
  axios.get('/api/search/', {
    params: {
      q: value
    }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
  });
```

since any number of parameters added will not make the URL clumsy, an alternate for

```
axios.get('/api/search?q=${this.value}').
```

and on the server

```
router.get('/api/search', someController.someFunction)
```

and in your controller

```
if(req.query.hasOwnProperty('q')){
    var q = req.query.q;
}
```